Is there a way to write separate logs for every fork from failsafe / surefire maven plugins?
We use maven-failsafe-plugin for running integration tests concurrently with <forkCount>, so we will have multiple JVMs in different processes running tests in parallel.
The failsafe plugins logs all the output of the tests, but the lines of different forks are mixed up and it is hard to understand what is going on.
Is there a way to write the log output of the surefire plugin to files (one file per forked process) instead of printing it to stdout? It feels weird that this is not a common problem.
The application under test is a Spring Boot application.
I am aware that I can write the output to a file per test and that it is available in target/failsafe-reports/<SomeTest>.xml. This is already good, but we recently had cases where  data of one test leaked to another and in this case it would be really helpful, to have a logfile per fork, so one can see the order in which the tests were executed.
I looked into replacing the Slf4j SimpleLogger of mvn with logback, because with logback it should be possible, but as far as I could see this is not possible without modifying the mvn installation itself, but I would like to keep the changes only local the project.
I could configure logback inside the application under test to log to these files, but then I would be missing these lines from failsafe plugin, that also contain valuable information and are necessary to understand what is actually going on:
[INFO] Running <SomeTest>,
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.856 s -- in <SomeTest>

In the end I gave up on maven logging. Instead I solved it on application side:
I created a logback-test.xml configuration file in src/test/resources/ with this content:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
  <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />
  <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />

  <property name="LOG_FILE" value="target/failsafe-reports/logs/integration-tests-${PID:-0}.log"/>

  <root level="${logback.level:-info}">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
  </root>
</configuration>

It will create one log file per process id.
Then I also added a Spring bean with methods annotated with @BeforeTestMethod and @AfterTestMethod reacting to the corresponding events to add into the log output when a test starts and ends.
